# Sending a CSV file Server to Client

Tags: go, tcp

I've just recently started trying to learn Go and I'm trying to write a small server/client application for sending a csv file, from a server to a client. I'm running into an invalid type error when trying to encode a struct into BigEndian binary. My struct seems to already be in a binary format, I'm unsure why I get the following error:

Error writing binary buffer to big endian  binary.Write: invalid type *main.DataPack

Also, I'd like to keep the TCP connection open after sending the file, that's why I'm not using io.Copy.

Currently I'm triggering the handling of the file upload through by sending a '\x00' byte:

```
// Server
package main 

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "os"
    "encoding/binary"
    "bytes"

)


type DataPack struct {
    Length   int64
    Contents []byte
}

func main() {

    absPath, _ := filepath.Abs("./progs.csv")

    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(absPath)
    fmt.Println("%s",data)

    tel, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:23")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for {
        conn, err := tel.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("above filehandler")
        go fileHandler(conn)
    }
}

func fileHandler(conn net.Conn) {

    buf := make([]byte, 0)
    buf = append(buf, '\x00')
    conn.Write(buf)
    absPath, _ := filepath.Abs("./progs.csv")

    file, err := os.Open(absPath)
    defer file.Close()

    fi, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Fatal error reading file: ", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("This is the length of the file: ", fi.Size())

    data := &DataPack{Length: fi.Size()} // , Contents: }

    data.Contents = make([]byte, data.Length)
    n, err := file.Read(data.Contents)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error reading contents into struct: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("tried to read file contents: ", n)
    fmt.Println("DataPack: %+v", data) 

    buf1 := new(bytes.Buffer)
    err = binary.Write(buf1, binary.BigEndian, &data)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error writing binary buffer to big endian ", err)
    }
    conn.Write(buf1.Bytes())  
}
```

Here is the client

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
    "bufio"
)

const (
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 23
)

func main() {

addr := strings.Join([]string{host, strconv.Itoa(port)}, ":")
client := NewClient()
var err error

client.socket, err = net.Dial("tcp", addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("error setting up socket: %s", err)
}

for {

    m := bufio.NewReader(client.socket)
    b, err := m.ReadByte()
    if err != nil {

        fmt.Println("here is the error: ", err)
    }
    if b == '\x00'{
        fmt.Println("about to receive a file!!!")
        b, _ := m.ReadByte()
        fmt.Println("just got another byte ", b )
    }

} 

log.Printf("Over")
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## why you get the error

Visit https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write

> Write writes the binary representation of data into w. Data must be a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values, or a pointer to such data.

`type DataPack struct {
    Length   int64
    Contents []byte
}`

`Contents` isn't a fixed-size value, so you got the invalid type error.

## how to solve it

1. go binary
2. json
3. others

Comment: Thank you for the comment @shal, what would be the best way to handle this in binary if you are unsure of Contents size? So you could handle a large Vs. a small CSV file

Comment: @MattLock U could send the file directly and add special characters at the end, such as `\r\n`. Client read the buffer and split it according to the special characters.

Comment: I looked into io.Copy for sending the file directly but, I was hoping to keep the TCP connection open after the transfer, the copy calls seems to close it once the file has been transferred.

Comment: `io.Copy` won't close the TCP connection. Could you tell me where you think the code will close the connection. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L363